# Why does QProcessEnviroment return an empty QStringList?

Tags: linux, qt, unix, environment-variables

I use Ubuntu 12.04.

Code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QProcessEnvironment environment;
    qDebug() << environment.toStringList();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
()
```

`env` command returns a non-empty list of environment variables.

How to solve this problem? What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment()` to get the environment of the calling process. Now you're just creating an empty environment. See [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocessenvironment.html#systemEnvironment).